# Laravel 8.83.2 Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\Dispatcher] is not instantiable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I've been trying to set up my Laravel 8.83.2 project on an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using PHP version 8.1.3, and no matter what I try I get the following error:

```
In Container.php line 1089:
                                                                     
  Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\Dispatcher] is not instantiable.
```

This occurs while trying to run any artisan command, no other stacktrace is being outputted either.

This does not seem to be an issue when setting the project up on our alpine CI/CD, any ideas what is causing this? I can provide further information about the project if any is needed.

Comment: Trying to instance `interface` is absurd - and there's no code provided to reproduce. As a rule of thumb, the last one line of a stacktrace doesn't even matter too much; please provide the code along with the FULL stacktrace.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I'm not trying to instantiate an interface, I was trying to run `artisan serve` or any artisan command at all when I got the error. Unfortunately, that's also the only output of artisan when the problem occurs. the problem is fixed now, I'll try to reproduce it and file a bug to Laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like a mismatch problem with versions

1. try to clear `bootstarp/cache` by hand
2. try to remove `vendor` and install again with a specific PHP version like `php8.1 composer install`
3. also its better to reload your FastCGI with something like `service php-fpm reload` to avoid hitting opcache (if you are using it in CLI just a `ctrl+c` would do the job)

Comment: When freshly deployed, there isn't supposed to be any cache ...

Comment: I deduced from the question that he is using an old project and in a fresh CICD there is no problem so I suggested that. also it seems that this fixed his problem (like I had a similar one in the past)